# Show current amount of rows being read in Oracle

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I am currently developing a small app that will execute huge queries, with huge amount of rows as a result (~500k, up to a million). All those queries are executed in a BGWorker, one by one. There is a BGWorker for SQL Server 2008 and another one for Oracle 11g.

So, the question is: Is there a way to show the current amount of rows being read in mid-execution of a query in C#?

As an example, any query being run in PL/SQL shows this number, which is updated every millisecond and reflects how many rows are being returned:

[image: PL/SQL Execution]

(Yes, that number of rows sometimes makes me cringe.)

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET, an ORM, etc?

Comment: I'm using ADO.NET here. It's just a small WinForms app.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611972/how-to-best-show-progress-info-when-using-ado-net From what I can find, even with ORMs there doesn't seem to be much support for this.

Comment: I don't understand the issue: why don't you just declare a counter at the `DataReader` creation and simply increment it after each `Read()`?

Comment: Because the Read() method is called after the query is completed. What I'm trying to do is get the amounts of rows being read WHILE they are being read.

Comment: No: the `Read` command is called each time a row is fetched and anyway this is exactly what happens behind the scenes of the sql editor in your image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) (my emphasis)

> The `DataReader` provides an **unbuffered** stream of data that allows **procedural** logic to **efficiently** process results from a data source sequentially. The DataReader is a good choice when retrieving large amounts of data because the data is not cached in memory.

and more specifically to your question

> You use the `Read` method of the `DataReader` object to obtain a row
>   from the results of the query.

As per my comments, what happens behind the scenes of the sql editor in your image is that it just defines a counter after the `DataReader` creation and simply increments it after each `Read()`

Comment: Well apparently I was missing a perfectly valid and well known feature of the DbDataReader, after being using it for years. Thanks for clearing it out!